# Summing over infinite numbers of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, summation

Let $\mathbf{I}$ be a identity matrix, and $\mathbf{A}$ be a symmetric matrix in which every entry $a_{ij}$ follows $0 \le a_{ij} < 1$.

I want to get $\mathbf{S} = \mathbf{I} + \mathbf{A} + \mathbf{A}^2 + \ldots$ (eq.1)

By multiplying $\mathbf{A}$ to both side of (eq.1), we get

$\mathbf{AS} = \mathbf{A} + \mathbf{A}^2 + \mathbf{A}^3 + \ldots$ (eq.2)

By (eq.1) - (eq.2), we get

$\mathbf{(I-A)S} = \mathbf{I}$, and thus $\mathbf{S} = (\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{A})^{-1}$ (eq.3)

Here comes my question.  By setting $\mathbf{A} := \left[\begin{array}{ccc}0 & 0.9 & 0.9 \\ 0.9 & 0 & 0.9 \\ 0.9 & 0.9 & 0\end{array}\right]$, every entry in $\mathbf{S}$ should be non-negative, since every entry in every matrix in the RHS of (eq.1) is non-negative.

However, if I calculate $\mathbf{S}$ by (eq.3), I got

$\mathbf{S} \approx \left[\begin{array}{ccc}-0.066 & -0.592 & -0.592 \\ -0.592 & -0.066 & -0.592 \\ -0.592 & -0.592 & -0.066\end{array}\right]$

Why do these entries become negative?  Did I do anything wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The largest eigenvalue of your matrix is $1.8$ as found by [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvalues%20%7B%7B0,.9,.9%7D,%7B.9,0,.9%7D,%7B.9,.9,0%7D%7D), so your sum does not converge.  It is like summing $x^i$ to get $\frac 1{1-x}$, which works fine for $|x| \lt 1$.  Your sum will converge if all the eigenvalues of the matrix are less than $1$ in absolute value.